# OpenGL storing variables per shape without any duplicates

Tags: c, opengl, vertex, vertex-buffer

I've been working on a sprite renderer, and I have rectangles being rendered correctly, but now I want to rotate them and perhaps add textures to the endeavor. However, I don't know how to store the angle, for example, without duplicating the data. Currently, every vertex has its position, and it would be a waste to repeat every angle, textureatlas_index, etc. 4 times for each rectangle mesh. So here's the question, is there an efficient way to store variables such as angles, or textureatlas_indexes per shape, and not per vertex?

Edit: one more thing, my sprite renderer does have a maximum capacity, so it's not dynamically sized, but I can't access that maximum capacity pre-runtime, so static arrays are not really an option.

I'm targetting 3.3 core

Comment: Which OpenGL version are you targeting?

Comment: @derhass 3.3 core

Comment: @Whitclaws. You can for example use an [UBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) or [TBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Texture) to store the per-rectangle attributes only once.  If you use a fixed number of 4 or 6 vertices per rectangle, you could than just use an index derived from  `gl_VertexID/4` or `gl_VertexID/6` to index into your per-rectangle attributes. Another option would be to use [instancing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing), but I wouldn't recommend that because perf  will not be optimal with so few vertices.

Comment: @derhass UBOs wouldnt work in this case because uniform blocks require compile-time contants for arrays, but I'll have a look into TBOs

Comment: No idea what you mean by "compile time constants for arrays". If you mean the array size - well, nobody forces you to use the whole array size, so it is more of a limit than everything else.

Comment: What's wrong with using ordinary uniforms or a UBO and uploading a vec4 for the colour and a matrix for the rotation before drawing each rectangle? This would only be a bad idea if you wanted to draw all your rectangles in one draw call. But I don't think you mentioned that in your question.

Comment: @Zebrafish Well my bad then, I settled for a texture buffer object and gl_VertexId / 4 to get the demanded shape

Comment: I suggested glAttribDivisor in a wrong answer below, but if you are using instancing it would work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled for a streamed texture buffer and gl_VertexId/4 to get the current rectangle's index